# How to get date and time from SQL Server to python?

Tags: python, sql-server

I need to get date and time in SQL Server table as two variables (one for date and other for time) in Python. I have googled and searched in many websites, but what I found is coding only for sending data and time from python to SQL Server.

I am using Python3.

I also want to know if there is any possibility in SQL Server to find difference or interval between 2 time instances in a table.

For example:

```
ID  Data         Time     Alarm
--------------------------------
1   12-01-2020   12:02     ON
2   12-01-2020   13:05     OFF
```

What I need to know is the time interval (duration) between Alarm ON and OFF instances. If it's possible to subtract or find difference between times 13:05 and 12:02, then the duration of Alarm ON period will be 01:03. But I don't think that the operation 13:05 - 12:02 = 01:03 is directly possible in SQL Server. If there any way to get this operation done by using any of type conversion methods inside SQL Server itself, kindly let me know.

Comment: Is there a reason you are splitting the date and the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is quite capable of working with dates/ times/ datetimes/ etc.

```
DECLARE @date1 DATE = '20200112';
DECLARE @date2 DATE = '20200112';
DECLARE @time1 TIME = '12:02';
DECLARE @time2 TIME = '13:05';

--Difference between two times
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @time1, @time2);

--Put the dates and times back together
DECLARE @datetime1 DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(HOUR, @time1) * 60 + DATEPART(MINUTE, @time1), CONVERT(DATETIME, @date1));
DECLARE @datetime2 DATETIME = DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(HOUR, @time2) * 60 + DATEPART(MINUTE, @time2), CONVERT(DATETIME, @date2));

--Difference between two date times
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @datetime1, @datetime2);
```

I get 63 minutes (or 1:03) either way I do this.

As a bonus, if you want to make 63 minutes into 01:03 then you could always do this:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), ROUND(63 / 60, 0)), 2) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), 63 % 60), 2);
```

Gives me an answer of `01:03`